# How do I locate an input field that uses a dynamic selector in TestCafe

Tags: testing, dynamic, css-selectors, automated-tests, testcafe

I attempt to create an end to end test with testcafe that fills out a form when running the test fails for a particular field because the selector cannot be found.

I am using the following line of code to locate and attempt to update the field

```
.typeText('#formControl363', '1.25.1979');
```

This is the element below

```css
<input type="text" class="form-control_date ng-isolate-scope form-control form-control_s form-control_color-blue ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-date ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-date-in-range" ng-class="cssClass" ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="ngRequired()" ng-disabled="ngDisabled()" uib-datepicker-popup="" popup-placement="auto bottom-left" is-open="status.isOpened" ng-click="status.isOpened=true" datepicker-options="datepickerOptions" datepicker-append-to-body="appendToBody !== false" placeholder="Select Date" id="formControl363" required="required">
```

Right-clicking the element and copying the selector gives me #formControl363

```
1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

       > | Selector('#formControl363')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use other ways to select element: page hierarchy, class selectors, attribute selectors, etc.
See similar questions in TestCafe Support Center:

- https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T240378/testcafe-how-to-get-dynamic-id-from-scripting
- https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T148029/testcafe-how-to-write-a-test-if-element-ids-are-generated-automatically-for-example-in